# Logout linkbutton is not firing click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement my login and logout through my webpage. There are two panels which toggle. On my page load, the logout panel is made invisible so that the user may only see the login link. After logging in the login panel is made invisible and the logout panel is made visible where the logout link is there for logging out. but the logout linkbutton is not even firing the click event. This is what i see in the browser window at the bottom when i try to click the logout link button [image: This is what i see in the browser window at the bottom when i try to click the logout link button]
This is my aspx page-

```
<div>
<asp:Panel ID="LoginPanel" runat="server">
    <ul class="style1">
                <li>Username</li>
                <li><asp:TextBox ID="LoginEmail" runat="server" Width="90%" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox></li>

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email Required" ControlToValidate="LoginEmail" ForeColor="#CC0000" Font-Italic="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <li>Password</li>
                <li><asp:TextBox ID="LoginPassword" runat="server" Width="90%" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></li>

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password Required" ControlToValidate="LoginPassword" ForeColor="#CC0000" Font-Italic="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <li><asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Login" class="btn btn-default" onclick="LoginButton_Click"/>

                &nbsp;New User?<asp:HyperLink ID="new_user" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Registration.aspx">Register Here</asp:HyperLink></li>
    </ul>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="LogoutPanel" runat="server">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LogoutLink" runat="server" Text="Logout" 
                    onclick="LogoutLink_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
</div>
```

This is my cs code-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class UserMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    ConnectionClass cl;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    string sql;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LogoutPanel.Visible = false;
            cl = new ConnectionClass();
        }
    }
    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sql = "select Id, Email_, Password_, Block from MemberLogin where Email_='" + LoginEmail.Text + "'";
        cl = new ConnectionClass();
        cl.establishConnection();
        cl.createReaderCommand(sql);
        dr = cl.executeReaderCommand();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            if (LoginPassword.Text == dr["Password_"].ToString())
            {
                if (dr["Block"].ToString() == "False")
                {
                    Session["user"] = dr[0].ToString();
                    LoginPanel.Visible = false;
                    LogoutPanel.Visible = true;
                    //Response.Write("login successful");
                }
            }
        }
        cl.closeConnection();
    }
    protected void LogoutLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("AdminLogin.aspx");
    }
}
```

This is on my master page. I need to solve this problem very soon. Please help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__DoPostBackWithOptions` call associated with the LinkButton is related to the presence of the validators in your page. Setting `CausesValidation` to `false` would replace it by the "regular" `__doPostBack`:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LogoutLink" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ... />
```

The validators shown in your markup being in a Panel with `Visible = false`, they should not be active. But since I don't see anything else that could prevent the postback, turning off the validation for the LinkButton would at least eliminate that possible cause.

By the way, if you have many controls and validators in your form, you may consider grouping them with validation groups. That would allow each button (or other controls causing a postback) to trigger only the relevant validators:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1a" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1a" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt1a" ValidationGroup="Group1" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1b" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1b" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt1b" ValidationGroup="Group1" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" />
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button1" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt2a" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group2" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv2a" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt2a" ValidationGroup="Group2" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt2b" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group2" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv2b" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt2b" ValidationGroup="Group2" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" />
<asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button2" ValidationGroup="Group2" />
```

In the example above, a click on `btn1` would cause a postback even if `txt2a` is empty, because they don't belong to the `Group1` validation group.

Comment: that worked but now every link on my page is not firing click button. so what should i do? add causevalidation to each and every control? there are so many of them!

Comment: One or several validators must be active and prevent the postback. In order to find the "guilty" ones, you can gradually set `Enabled="false"` on the validators in markup until the postback works. You could then decide in which situations each one should be enabled or disabled (in code-behind), so that you would not have to set `CausesValidation="false"` on all your buttons. On the other hand, that attribute makes sense for controls that clearly should not cause validation, like the logout LinkButton.

Comment: I added a comment about validation groups in my answer.